# Is TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK enough to prevent INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I have a transaction including several tables. I need to prevent inserts  to  `TABLE_TO_BE_LOCKED` after I have deleted some records from `EDITED_TABLE`. Currently I am using `TABLOCKX`

```
DELETE EDITED_TABLE FROM EDITED_TABLE
left join TABLE_TO_BE_LOCKED  with (TABLOCKX) on ....
 WHERE ...
```

I need to prevent inserting new records to `TABLE_TO_BE_LOCKED` but I would like to preserve possibility to read it. After the `DELETE` `TABLE_TO_BE_LOCKED` is still not changed and this is the reason for explicit locking.

Can I use `TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK` instead of `TABLOCKX`?

Note:

I know about [How to lock a table for inserting in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522286/how-to-lock-a-table-for-inserting-in-sql). However there is result don't do it to prevent duplicities in primary key.

Comment: Why not just use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and transactions?

Comment: @millimoose: does not exist in SQL Server

Answer (score 5):

If the table has writes to in a transaction, then exclusive locks will be held until the end of the transaction. You can't enable SELECT in this case unless you use NOLOCK on the SELECT, but then you'll see deleted rows.

`TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK` will simply locks the whole table exclusively until the end of the transaction

It sounds like you're trying to fix your chosen solution: with more information we may be able to offer a better one that does what you want without lock hints. For example, if your transaction needs a consistent view of deleted data not affected by other transactions doing INSERTS then you could try one or more of

- OUTPUT clause to work on the set of data you started with
- Use SERIALIZABLE only to preserve the range (which is HOLDLOCK BTW)
- Use [SNAPSHOT isolation modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

After comments...

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM TABLE_TO_BE_LOCKED
WHERE .. -- or JOIN to EDITED_TABLE

DELETE EDITED_TABLE FROM EDITED_TABLE
left join #temp  with (TABLOCKX) on ....
 WHERE ...

-- do stuff with #temp

COMMIT
```

Comment: I have modified the question in attempt to express the problem more clearly.

Comment: @IvanH: thanks. Why do you want TABLE_TO_BE_LOCKED to not have INSERTS? Is it read later?

Comment: It is processed later on in transaction, but I need to be sure that there are no new records in it in the time I use it.

Comment: Select the records into a temp table or table variable then to preserve the state

Comment: The table can contain several tens (even hundreds) of records. I don't think it is very efficient to make its copy to for transaction which is supposed to ran ~1s. The EDITED_TABLE is temporary. I need to preserve the state of TABLE_TO_BE_LOCKED.

Comment: @IvanH: neither is locking a table for the transaction. But you can try HOLDLOCK, TABLOCK if you want to block other writers

Comment: Maybe I am not expressing correctly but I need to block other writers (I know what I am doing).

Comment: Use HOLDLOCK, TABLOCK then

Comment: Would you put the last statement to the answer? I accept it then.